# how to uncouple differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following equations:
$$
\dot{u}_i(t)=-\mu_i u_i(t) + \sum_{j\neq i} J_{ij}u_j(t) \quad \text{with }1\leq i\leq N
$$ 
although this is a linear system this is a real pain to solve when $N$ becomes large. Is there a smart change of variables to uncouple these equations and solve them independently?

My attempt:

Assume $J$ has a complete set of orthogonal eigenvectors $\{\vec{x}^{(k)}\}$, then we can write $\vec{u}(t)=\sum_k \sigma_k(t)\vec{x}^{(k)}$ for some coefficients $\sigma_k(t)$. Thus:

\begin{equation}
    \sum_k \dot{\sigma}_k(t) x^{(k)}_i = -\mu_i\sum_k \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i + \sum_{j,k,l}\lambda_l \sigma_k(t) x^{(l)}_i y^{(l)}_j x^{(k)}_j
\end{equation}
where we use:
\begin{equation}
    J_{ij}=\sum_l^N \lambda_l x_i^{(l)}y_j^{(l)}
\end{equation}
with $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ the right and left normalised eigenvectors:
\begin{equation}
    \sum_i x_i^{(m)}y_i^{(n)}=\delta_{mn}
\end{equation}
Thus:
\begin{equation}
    \sum_k \dot{\sigma}_k(t) x^{(k)}_i = -\mu_i\sum_k \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i + \sum_{k,l}\lambda_l \sigma_k(t) x^{(l)}_i \delta_{kl}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sum_k \dot{\sigma}_k(t) x^{(k)}_i = -\mu_i\sum_k \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i + \sum_{k}\lambda_k \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \boxed{\sum_k \dot{\sigma}_k(t) x^{(k)}_i = \sum_k (\lambda_k-\mu_i) \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i}
\end{equation}

Trying to uncouple the equations, by multiplying by the left eigenvector and summing over $i$:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k,i} \dot{\sigma}_k(t) x^{(k)}_i y^{(l)}_i = \sum_{k,i} (\lambda_k-\mu_i) \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i  y^{(l)}_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{\sigma}_l(t) = \sum_{k,i} (\lambda_k-\mu_i) \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i  y^{(l)}_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{\sigma}_l(t) = \sum_{i,k} \lambda_k\sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i  y^{(l)}_i-\sum_{k,i}\mu_i \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i  y^{(l)}_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{\sigma}_l(t) = \sum_{k} \lambda_k\sigma_k(t) \delta_{kl}-\sum_{k,i}\mu_i \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i  y^{(l)}_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{\sigma}_l(t) = \lambda_l\sigma_l(t) -\sum_{k,i}\mu_i \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i  y^{(l)}_i
\end{equation}

Which is exactly my starting point, thus zero progress...

Any hints is really appreciated! thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. This is a linear ODE, so the best solution method is putting the coefficient matrix in Jordan canonical form and exponentiating. Yes this is computationally difficult, but I don't know of a better way to treat such systems.

Comment: I edited the question, maybe you will see something I don't!

Comment: Look up something called Jordan canonical form if you haven't. I won't show you how to compute it (because I'm not that experienced with it myself), but I can explain how it leads you to a solution if you want. For a partial answer to your question, what's to stop you from setting $J_{ii} = -\mu_i$ and then treating it as a typical linear ode?

Comment: You need to use the eigen decomposition of $-M+J$, where $M=\diag(\mu_i)_{i=1..n}$. Why did you separate the diagonal and non-diagonal entries in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call it zero progress. For example, if all the $\mu_i$ are equal to some $\mu$ using the relation $\sum_i x_i^{(m)}y_i^{(n)}=\delta_{mn}$ you obtain
\begin{equation}
\dot{\sigma}_l(t) = \lambda_l\sigma_l(t) -\sum_{k,i}\mu \sigma_k(t) x^{(k)}_i  y^{(l)}_i = \lambda_l\sigma_l(t) -\sum_{k} \sigma_k(t) \underbrace{\sum_i \mu x^{(k)}_i  y^{(l)}_i}_{\mu \delta_{kl}}
\end{equation}
i.e
\begin{equation}
\dot{\sigma}_l(t) = \lambda_l\sigma_l(t) -\mu \sigma_l(t).
\end{equation}

---

To see what happened, we can rewrite your computation in matrix form. With
$$J= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & J_{12}& J_{13} & \ldots & J_{1n}\\
J_{21} & 0 & J_{23} & \ldots & J_{2n} \\
J_{31} & J_{32} &0& \ldots & J_{2n} \\
\vdots & & & \ddots& \vdots \\
J_{n1} & J_{n2} &J_{n3}&\ldots &0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$D= \begin{pmatrix} \mu_1 & 0& 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & \mu_2 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0&\mu_3& \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & & & \ddots& \vdots \\
0 & 0 &0&\ldots & \mu_n \end{pmatrix}$$
the system writes as
$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{u}(t) = (-D+J)\vec{u}(t).$$

Your computation was equivalent to the diagonalization of $J$, i.e choose a $P$ such that
$$P J P^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & & &\\
& \ddots& \\
& & \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}$$
in order to write
$$\frac{d}{dt}(P\vec{u})(t)=P\frac{d}{dt}\vec{u}(t) = P(-D+J)P^{-1} P\vec{u}(t)=(-PDP^{-1}+PJP^{-1}) (P\vec{u}(t)).$$
With $\vec{\sigma} = P \vec{u}$ this leads to your last equation:
$$\left(\frac{d}{dt} \vec{\sigma}(t) \right)_l =\left(P DP^{-1} \vec{\sigma} \right)_l-\left(P JP^{-1} \vec{\sigma} \right)_l = \sum_k \underbrace{\left( P D P^{-1}\right)_{lk}}_{\sum_i \mu_i x_i^{(k)} y_i^{(l)}} \sigma_k-\lambda_l \sigma_l.  $$

So what you gained by simplifying $J$ was lost by "complexifying" $D$, as a basis which diagonalize $J$ do not necessarily diagonalize $D$ (this is what happened for the case $D=\mu Id$).

---

We see, as Charles Hudgins pointed out in the comments, that a best method would be to diagonalize directly the matrix $-D+J$. If it were possible, i.e with $Q$ such that
$$Q(-D+J)Q^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} \eta_1 & & &\\
& \ddots& \\
& & \eta_n \end{pmatrix}$$
the equation is simply
$$ \frac{d}{dt}(Q \vec{u})_l(t) = \mu_l (Q \vec{u})_l(t).$$

Unfortunately, not all matrices can be diagonalized. In $\mathbb{C}$ we can at least obtain a triangular system.

But the best method, as written in the comments, is to use the Jordan normal form for easy computation of the exponential of the matrix.